# How can I manipulate a 3D object into a specific position in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

I have been working on a 3D `.obj` file in Photoshop.

Now that I have the texture finished, I want to render a showcase image. I want the object to lay on it's side on the ground.

I've tried using the menu option <kbd>3D</kbd> > <kbd>Snap object to ground plane</kbd>; but that just snaps the object to the ground using the current position.

When selecting the object mesh, there's a box that appears around it. What I need is to place one of those faces perfectly on the ground place, so it looks like a real object laying on the ground.

**How can I rotate my 3D object to place one of the faces on a horizontal plane, so that it looks realistically like that object is laying on the ground?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Head on over here, and read up on what I'm about to mention:

http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/essential-3d-concepts-tools-photoshop.html

SLIDE the object to where you want it, then ROTATE it the way you want it.

Then position your camera as you desire. It won't be fun, will be clunky and unresponsive. Photoshop is not good at this stuff.

Well done on getting as far as you have. I can't imagine building anything 3D in Photoshop. If you've managed that, proper 3D software like 3ds Max is going to be a welcome breath of fresh air when you get there. And you're going to love it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did use 3Ds Max in the past and that's kind of why I was expecting PS to have something to easily reset the views after I move everything around to check how the texture is looking. I ended up using the coordinates properties to reset everything (mesh, camera, scene), and that seems to do the trick, I wish it was easier.

Comment: Combustion used to be good at this stuff. But now you'll have to use plugins that work well with After Effects to get the functionality you're really looking for... it's still not ideal. Graphic design at this level (3D apps) has progressed far further than 2D (technically + functions and features) but it's nowhere near where it could/should be.

Comment: Sorry, by "plugins that work well with After Effects" I mean texture plugins for 3ds Max. Not After Effects or Photoshop plugins.